# How orchestration is different from automation?

Tags: kubernetes, redhat

In IT industry orchestration is a common word nowadays. Mostly used in different process automation tools/systems. How orchestration is different from automation? and why it's called orchestration?

Answer (score 0):

Orchestration is a type of automation that involves the coordination and control of multiple tasks or processes.  Whereas Automation is the process of automating tasks or processes, while orchestration is more focused on creating a unified process from multiple tasks or processes. Orchestration is also known as workflow automation, as it is used to automate and manage the flow of tasks or processes. The term orchestration comes from the idea of 'orchestrating' tasks or processes to create a unified process.

Refer to this [Blog1](https://phoenixnap.com/blog/orchestration-vs-automation#:%7E:text=Automation%20refers%20to%20automating%20a,integrating%20it%20with%20other%20systems) and [Blog2](https://www.hitechnectar.com/blogs/it-automation-vs-orchestration/) for more information.

Comment: @user3396478 : Is your question addressed? Please accept and upvote the answer for the greater visibility of the community  if you got the required information.